# SQL question I have a table shown below need output like ba, ba, ba

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
col1
a
b
a
b
a
b
```

Trying to get an output like ba ,ba, ba

Comment: How do you know col1 is in that order? Is there another column that indicates that is the order? What if it were `c, a, a, c, d, c`? Should the result be `ac ,ca, cd`, or something else? Why? Please show more than one simple example and/or describe the rules.

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  Without a column that specifies an ordering, your question does not make sense.  Also, why are you using unsupported software?

Answer (score 0):

A few steps will get you the correct result:

- Copy the data to a temp table
- Add an identity column to the temp table
- Join the temp table to itself using odd\even rows

Try this code:

```
create table xtmp(col1 char)

insert xtmp values ('a'),('b'),('a'),('b'),('a'),('b'),('a'),('b')

select * into #tmp from xtmp
alter table #tmp add id int identity(1,1) not null

select evenrow.col1 + oddrow.col1 col from 
(select * from #tmp where id%2=0) evenrow
join 
(select * from #tmp where id%2=1) oddrow
on evenrow.id = oddrow.id+1
```

Output

```
col
ba
ba
ba
ba
```